# Is standard eigenvalue optimization problem convex

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For any arbitrary  symmetric matrix A , is the standard eigenvalue problem convex

$ \lambda_{max}(A)= \max_{\|x\| \leq1} x^{T}Ax$

Comment: The maximum eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix is a convex function of its elements. But as an optimization problem in $x$, it is not convex, unless $A$ is negative semidefinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Michael for catching my previous errors.

You need to be careful with terminology here.

In the following, I am assuming that $A$ is symmetric.

The **function** $\phi(A) = \max_{\|x\|\le 1} \langle x, Ax \rangle$ is always convex
because it is the $\sup$ of a collection of convex (in fact, linear) functions
$A \mapsto \langle x, Ax \rangle$.

However, the function $\phi$ is not necessarily equal to the maximum eigenvalue function. In general, $\phi(A) = \max(0, \lambda_\max(A))$.

If you restrict the $x$s, then we have
$\lambda_\max(A) = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \langle x, Ax \rangle$ (which **is** a 
convex function of $A$ for the same reasons as above).

However, the optimisation problem $\max_{\|x\|\le 1} \langle x, Ax \rangle =
-\min_{\|x\|\le 1} \langle x, (-A)x \rangle$ is not necessarily a convex program.
 If you restrict $A$ to the 
cone of negative semidefinite matrices, then the optimisation problem is convex,
but the solution is trivially $0$.

For example, if $A=+1$, then the problem is $\max \{ x^2 | |x| \le 1 \}$
which is not a convex program.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks for catching that. I had some $\min,\max$ confusion.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: I think I have maximised the number of errors in my answer...

Comment: In fact, I think it is *only* a convex program if $A$ is negative semidefinite. Otherwise it is non-convex. Well, at least this is the case if $A$ is symmetric since then the Hessian of the maximization objective is $2A$. Not sure about non-symmetric $A$ though.