# Sum of squared maximization with a norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I have the following optimization
\begin{align}
\max_{\|x\|^2\le1} \|Lx - y\|
\end{align}
where $L$ is a lower triangular and $y$ is a given vector.
Does it admit a closed-form solution?

I am interested in the general case where $L$ may be not invertible and even not square, but any progress under some assumptions will be muchnappreciated.

The motivation is to understand the standard least squares method but as a game from the "adversarial" point of view: $y$ is a measurement sequence and $x$ is the set of possible states from $y = Lx + n$.

Comment: Is $L$ square and lower triangular? Is it invertible?

Comment: What do you mean by $y$ is a given "sequence"? Do you mean that $y$ is a vector?

Comment: @BenGrossmann. Thanks, I have edited the question. The sequence terminology stems from my ambition to generalize it to infinite dimension afterwards :)

Comment: What does this sentence mean : The motivation is to understand the standard least squares method but as a game from the "adversarial" point of view.

Comment: The optimization model can be reformulated as a semi-definite programming model, which can be solved efficiently.

Comment: @Amir can it lead to closed form solution via necessary and sufficient KKT conditions?

Comment: @Morad As already shown in an answer, the optimal solution is among a set of candidate feasible solutions constructed by numerically solving some equations. It seems improbable that a closed form solution can be provided. The SDP KKT conditions also cannot be solved explicitly, but the reformulation allows you to efficiently obtain the optimal value using existing optimization solvers. In **a new answer**, using the spectral decomposition and KKT conditions, I presented a   solution procedure that seems **more straightforward** to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can consider the following **equivalent** objective:

$$\|Lx - y\|^2=x^T\color{blue}{L^TL}x-2y^TLx+y^Ty.$$

As $L^TL$ is a symmetric (positive semidefinite) matrix, it admits **the spectral decomposition**: $$\color{blue}{L^TL = Q^T \Lambda Q }$$ for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ with $Q^TQ=I$ and diagonal matrix $\Lambda \, (\ge 0)$. Then, defining $\color{blue}{z=Qx}$ and $\color{blue}{b:=2QL^Ty}$, the problem is equivalent to:

$$\color{blue}{\max_{\|z\|^2=1} \quad z^T\Lambda z-b^Tz+y^Ty }.$$

Note that here we consider the **equivalent** constraint $$\|x\|^2=x^Tx=x^TIx=x^TQ^TQx=z^Tz=\|z\|^2=1.$$ As the problem is convex *maximization* (maximization of the convex quadratic function $z^T\Lambda z-b^Tz+y^Ty$ over the convex set $\|z\|^2 \le 1$), there is an optimal solution on the boundary (at some extreme point), so the constraint $\|z\|^2 \le 1$ can be replaced with $\|z\|^2 = 1$.

For the $\color{blue}{\text{new problem}}$, from the KKT conditions, the maximizer is among normalized vectors $z$ (with $\|z\|^2=1$) that satisfy the following system:

$$\Lambda z-b+2\mu z=0  \equiv \\ \color{blue}{(\Lambda+2\mu I)z=b}$$

for some $\mu \in \mathbb R$ (note that as we consider the equality constraint  $\|z\|^2 = 1$, $\mu$ can be any number in $\mathbb R$). Now **we should find** all the feasible solutions of this system (**feasible KKT points**) by noting that $\color{blue}{\Lambda+2\mu I}$ **is a diagonal matrix, which simplifies the search procedure**. All the feasible KKT points can be obtained in the following **two steps**:

1. If some element $i$ of $b$ is $0$, then either $z_i$ is $0$ or $-2\mu$ is equal to the $i$th element of $\Lambda$, i.e., $\mu=-\frac{\lambda_i}{2}$. The first scenario is investigated in Step 2. Under the second scenario, $z_j=\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j- \lambda_i}$ for those $j$ with $b_j \neq 0$, $z_j=0$ for all other $j \neq i$. If this vector satisfies  $\|z\|^2=1$, then it is a feasible KKT point.
2. After fixing $z_j=0$ for any $j$ for which $b_j=0$, for the other $j$ we have $$z_j=\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j+2\mu}$$  where $\mu$ can be any solution of the following equation: $$\sum_{j\in[n]: b_j\neq 0} \left (\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j+2\mu} \right )^2=1.$$

After, fining all the feasible KKT points $z^{1},\dots, z^{m}$ (note that $m\ge 1$ as the feasible space is compact and the objective is continuous), we need to determine the one (or those) that maximizes the objective $z^T\Lambda z-b^Tz+y^Ty$, let us denote it by $z^*$. Finally, $x^*$ is any solution that satisfies $z^*=Qx^*$.

---

**Remark 1:** In Step 2, we need to find the roots $\mu$ of the following equation $$\sum_{j=1}^n \left (\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j+2\mu} \right )^2=1,$$ which involves a polynomial of degree $2n$. As the function has a **special** structure, it can be proven that it always has **at least two roots** and can have up to $2n$ roots (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4878261/1231520)). Thus, when none of the elements of $b$ is zero, we can have up to $2n$ candidate feasible KKT points. If $k$ elements of $b$ are zero, the maximum number of roots is $2(n-k)$ and we can have up to $k$ feasible KKT points from Step 1. Thus, **the number of candidate feasible KKT points obtained in Steps 1 and 2 can be from 2 up to $2n$**.

**Remark 2:** For the special case of $b = 0$, there are up to $n$ candidate feasible KKT points, obtained in Step 1 by setting $-2\mu$ to each of $\lambda_j, j=1,...,n$ (which are the eigenvalues of $L^TL$). The $n$ feasible KKT points are $$z^1=e_1,\dots,z^n=e_n.$$  Note that in this case, the feasible KKT corresponding to the largest $\lambda_j$ (which is the largest eigenvalue of $L^TL$) becomes the optimal solution and the optimal value becomes $\lambda_{\max}(L^TL)$, i.e., $$\max_{\|x\|^2 \le 1} \, x^TL^TLx=  \max_{\|z\|^2=1} \, z^T\Lambda z=\lambda_{\max}(L^TL),$$ which is a known [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1203874/1231520).

**Remark 3 ($\color{red}{\text{Update 1}}$):**

I just realized that, when none of the elements of $b$ is zero, the KKT point defined by **the smallest root** (denote it by $\mu_{min}$) of the equation:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \left (\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j+2\mu} \right )^2=1,$$

is **the optimal solution**. Let me first show that **the smallest root is always negative**. As all $\lambda_j, j=1,\dots, n$ are non-negative, the above equation **always has a negative root** in the interval

$$\left (-\infty, -\frac{\max_{j \in [n] }(\lambda_j)}{2} \right), $$

by observing that the LHS of the equation tends to $0$ as $\mu \to -\infty$ and tends to $+\infty$ as $2\mu \to \left (-\max_{j \in [n] }(\lambda_j) \right )^-$. Hence, we always have

$$2\mu_{min}<-\max_{j=1,\dots, n}\lambda_j \le 0.$$

Indeed, the feasible KKT vector $\tilde{z}$ defined by $\mu_{min}$ with

$$\tilde{z}_j=\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j+2\mu_{min}}, j=1,\dots, n$$

is the only candidate whose sign is opposite to the sign of the vector $b$ (located in the opposite orthant), that is,

$$\color{blue}{\text{sgn}  (\tilde{z}  )=-\text{sgn}(b)}.$$

**The above property allows** the feasible KKT point $\tilde{z}$ determined by the smallest root $\mu$ to have **the longest distance from the point $b$** among the other feasible KKT points.

**Remark 4 ($\color{red}{\text{Update 2}}$):**

Using the observation made in Remark 3, we can conclude that if for some $i$ we have

$$b_i=0$$
$$\lambda_i =\max_{j \in [n] }(\lambda_j)$$
$$\sum_{j \in [n]: \lambda_j \neq \lambda_i }\left(\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i} \right )^2<1,$$

then the feasible KKT point obtained for $2\mu=-\lambda_i$ from Step 1 is the optimal solution, that is, the following point (or points if we have $j \neq i$ with $\lambda_j=\lambda_i$):

$$\sum_{j \in [n]: \lambda_j=\lambda_i }z^2_j=1- \sum_{j \in [n]: \lambda_j \neq \lambda_i}\left(\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i} \right )^2, \\ z_j= \frac{b_j}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i} ,j \in [n]: \lambda_j\neq\lambda_i.$$

Otherwise, the feasible KKT point obtained in Step 2 for the smallest root of the equation:

$$\sum_{j \in [n]: b_j \neq 0} \left (\frac{b_j}{\lambda_j+2\mu} \right )^2=1,$$

is the optimal solution.

This follows from the fact that the optimal solution of the problem continuously depends on $b$. To reach the above observation, for those  $j$ with $b_j=0$, we can define $b_j=0+\epsilon $ and then use the point in Remark 3. Note that for $i$ with $b_i=\epsilon$ and $\lambda_i =\max_{j \in [n] }(\lambda_j)$, $2\mu_{\min} \to - \max_{j \in [n] }(\lambda_j)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^- .$

**Remark 5:** The problem is a non-convex optimization problem (known as convex maximization, or equivalently concave minimization), but it can be reformulated as a semi-definite programming model, which is a subclass of convex optimization, I have not provided it as the OP seeks a closed-form solution.

Comment: Why do you say convex? The objective function is convex while the criteria is maximization. On top of that you add non linear equality condition. It doesn't look like a convex optimization problem.

Comment: @Royi thanks for your feedback. I just said **convex maximization** (also, known as concave minimization, for which the optimal value is obtained on the boundary), I did not say that it is a **convex optimization problem** (i.e., convex minimization over a convex set). But you may note that this problem can be reformulated as a semi-definite programming model, which is a subclass of convex optimization (I did not provide it as the OP seeks a closed-form solution)

Comment: Thanks @Amir, it is very nice. Is there a simpler equation to determine $\mu$? minor: 1. typo in equation $\Lambda x - b..$ should be with $z$. 2. Should $\mu$ be non-negative?

Comment: @Morad please see the updated Remark 1 and new Remark 2.

Comment: @Morad I could finally figure out which root of the equation determines the optimal solution (please see the new remark).

Answer (score 8):

In the sequel, we assume that the matrices and vectors are real and the norm is Euclidean. If the field is complex, let $L=A+iB,\,\mathbf x=\mathbf p+i\mathbf q$ and $\mathbf y=\mathbf a+i\mathbf b$. The problem is then equivalent to its ‘realified’ version
$$
\max_{\|\mathbf p\|^2+\|\mathbf q\|^2\le1}\left\|
\pmatrix{A&-B\\ B&A}\pmatrix{\mathbf p\\ \mathbf q}-\pmatrix{\mathbf a\\ \mathbf b}\right\|.
$$

So, assume that we work over $\mathbb R$. Let $r=\operatorname{rank}(L)$ and $L=USV^T$ be an economic/compact singular value decomposition of $L$, where $S=\operatorname{diag}(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_r)$ is a positive diagonal matrix and each of $U$ and $V$ has $r$ orthonormal columns. Let $\mathbf v=V^T\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf z=U^T\mathbf y$, where $\mathbf v,\mathbf z\in\mathbb R^r$. Then $\|L\mathbf x-\mathbf y\|=\|S\mathbf v-\mathbf z\|$ and hence $\max_{\|\mathbf x\|\le1}\|L\mathbf x-\mathbf y\|=\max_{\|\mathbf v\|\le1}\|S\mathbf v-\mathbf z\|$. Since $S$ is invertible, the image of the open unit ball under $S$ is an open set. It follows that the maximiser $\mathbf v$ of the transformed problem $\max_{\|\mathbf v\|\le1}\|S\mathbf v-\mathbf z\|$ must occur at the boundary of the unit ball, i.e., it is a unit vector. The optimisation problem is therefore equivalent to maximising
$$
f(\mathbf v) = \|S\mathbf v-\mathbf z\|^2 = \mathbf v^TS^2\mathbf v - 2\mathbf v^TS\mathbf z + \|\mathbf z\|^2
$$
on the unit sphere $\|\mathbf v\|=1$.

This can be solved by the method of Lagrange multipliers, but a matrix-theoretic approach seems easier here. At a maximiser $\mathbf v$, we have $f(\mathbf v)\ge f(\mathbf w)$ for any unit vector $\mathbf w$. In particular, for any skew-symmetric matrix $K$, if we put $g(t)=f(e^{tK}\mathbf v)$, then $t=0$ will be a critical point of $g$. Therefore
$$
0=g'(0)=\operatorname{tr}\left(K^T(S^2\mathbf v\mathbf v^T-S\mathbf z\mathbf v^T)\right)
$$
for every skew-symmetric matrix $K$, meaning that $S^2\mathbf v\mathbf v^T-S\mathbf z\mathbf v^T$ is a symmetric matrix. Hence $S^2\mathbf v-S\mathbf z=\lambda \mathbf v$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, i.e., $(S^2-\lambda I)\mathbf v=S\mathbf z$. There are two cases:

1. If $\lambda\not\in\{s_1^2,s_2^2,\ldots,s_r^2\}$, then $S^2-\lambda I$ is invertible and
   $$
   \mathbf v=(S^2-\lambda I)^{-1}S\mathbf z.\tag{1}
   $$
   Since $\mathbf v$ is a unit vector, we must have
   $$
   1=\|\mathbf v\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^r\frac{s_i^2z_i^2}{(s_i^2-\lambda)^2}.
   $$
   Therefore the feasible choices of $\lambda$ are those real roots of the polynomial equation
   $$
   p(\lambda)
   =\prod_{j=1}^r(\lambda - s_i^2)^2
   -\sum_{i=1}^rs_i^2z_i^2\prod_{j\ne i}(\lambda - s_i^2)^2=0
   $$
   that lie outside $\{s_1^2,s_2^2,\ldots,s_r^2\}$. Hence there are at most $\deg p=2r$ feasible choices.
2. If $\lambda\in\{s_1^2,s_2^2,\ldots,s_r^2\}$, it solves the equation $(S^2-\lambda I)\mathbf v=S\mathbf z$ for some unit vector $\mathbf v$ if and only if $(S^2-\lambda I)(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z=S\mathbf z$ and $\|(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z\|\le1$. For each feasible $\lambda=s_i^2$, any unit vector of the form
   $$
   \mathbf v=(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z+\mathbf w;
   \quad\mathbf w\in\ker(S^2-\lambda I)
   $$
   will solve $(S^2-\lambda I)\mathbf v=S\mathbf z$. The choice of $\mathbf w$ is irrelevant — as long as it makes $\|\mathbf v\|=1$ — because it does not contribute to the value of $f(\mathbf v)$:
   \begin{align*}
   f(\mathbf v)
   &=\mathbf v^TS^2\mathbf v - 2\mathbf v^TS\mathbf z + \|\mathbf z\|^2\\
   &=\mathbf v^T(\lambda\mathbf v+S\mathbf z) - 2\mathbf v^TS\mathbf z + \|\mathbf z\|^2\\
   &=\lambda - \mathbf z^TS\mathbf v + \|\mathbf z\|^2
   \quad\text{(this is where we need $\|\mathbf v\|=1$)}\\
   &=\lambda - \mathbf z^TS\left[(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z+\mathbf w\right] + \|\mathbf z\|^2\\
   &=\lambda - \mathbf z^TS(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z  - \mathbf z^TS\mathbf w + \|\mathbf z\|^2\\
   &=\lambda - \mathbf z^TS(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z  - \mathbf v^T(S^2-\lambda I)\mathbf w + \|\mathbf z\|^2\\
   &=\lambda - \mathbf z^TS(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z + \|\mathbf z\|^2.\\
   \end{align*}
   In particular, when $\lambda=s_i^2$, we may always pick
   $$
   \mathbf v=(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z
   +\left(1-\|(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z\|^2\right)^{1/2}\mathbf e_i^{(r)}\tag{2}
   $$
   where $\mathbf e_i^{(r)}=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ denotes the $i$-th vector in the standard basis of $\mathbb R^r$.

These two cases are usually but not always mutually exclusive. For instance, when $\mathbf z$ is entrywise nonzero, only case 1 can occur. In contrast, when $S$ is not a scalar multiple of the identity matrix and $\mathbf z$ contains some zero entries, the equation $(S^2-\lambda I)\mathbf v=S\mathbf z$ may be solvable in both cases. So, in general, there may be up to $3r$ feasible choices of $\lambda$. Among them, pick the one that maximises $f(\mathbf v)=\|S\mathbf v-\mathbf z\|^2$, where $\mathbf v$ is computed according to $(1)$ or $(2)$. Then $\mathbf x=V\mathbf v$ will be a global maximiser to the original problem $\max_{\|\mathbf x\|\le1}\|L\mathbf x-\mathbf y\|$.

**Example.** Let $L=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0},\mathbf x=\pmatrix{x_1\\ x_2}$ and $\mathbf y=\pmatrix{y_1\\ y_2}$. We want to maximise $\|L\mathbf x-\mathbf y\|=\sqrt{|x_1-y_1|+|y_2|}$ subject to $x_1^2+x_2^2\le1$. Since $L$ is already a singular value matrix, we may take $U=V=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$ and $S=I_1=1$, so that $\mathbf v=V^T\mathbf x=x_1$ and $\mathbf z=U^T\mathbf y=y_1$.

In case 1, we require that $\lambda\not\in\{s_1^2,\ldots,s_r^2\}=\{s_1^2\}=\{1\}$, i.e., $\lambda\ne1$. We look for real roots $\lambda\ne1$ of the polynomial equation
$$
p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^2-y_1^2=0.
$$
Such real roots exist only when $y_1\ne0$. If this is the case, the feasible choices of $\lambda$ are $1\pm|y_1|$. We obtain
$$
x_1=\mathbf v
=(S^2-\lambda I)^{-1}S\mathbf z
=(1-\lambda)^{-1}y_1=\pm1
$$
and $\mathbf x=V\mathbf v=\pmatrix{\pm1\\ 0}$. Since $y_1\ne0$, one may verify that one of $x_1\in\{-1,1\}$ gives a global maximum of $\|L\mathbf x-\mathbf y\|=\sqrt{|x_1-y_1|+|y_2|}$ and the other is either a local minimum (when $|y_1|>1$) or a saddle point (when $0<|y_1|\le1$).

In case 2, again, since $\{s_1^2,\ldots,s_r^2\}=\{s_1^2\}=\{1\}$ is a singleton set, we only need to solve $(S^2-\lambda I)\mathbf v = S\mathbf z$ for a unit vector $\mathbf v$ where $\lambda=s_1^2=1$, i.e., we need to solve $(1-1)x_1 = 1y_1$ for $\|\mathbf v\|=|x_1|=1$. This is solvable only when $y_1=0$. If this is the case, the general solution is given by any
\begin{align*}
\mathbf v
&=(S^2-\lambda I)^+S\mathbf z+\mathbf w;\quad\mathbf w\in\ker(S^2-\lambda I)\\
&=(1-1)^+1y_1+\mathbf w;\quad\mathbf w\in\ker(1-1)\\
&=\mathbf w;\quad\mathbf w\in\ker(0)=\mathbb R^r=\mathbb R\\
\end{align*}
such that $\|\mathbf v\|=1$. This means $\mathbf v=\mathbf w=\pm1$ and $\mathbf x=V\mathbf v=\pmatrix{\pm1\\ 0}$. As mentioned earlier, the choice of $\mathbf w$ does not matter as long as it keeps $\mathbf v$ a unit vector. Here one may verify that both $\mathbf v=\mathbf w=1$ and $\mathbf v=\mathbf w=-1$ (i.e., $x_1=\pm1$) maximise the value of $\|L\mathbf x-\mathbf y\|=\sqrt{|x_1|+|y_2|}$.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. What is $(S^2-\lambda I)^+$ in case 2?

Comment: @Morad It is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $S^2-\lambda I$. Since $S$ is a diagonal matrix in this case, $(S^2-\lambda I)^+$ is simply the diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_r)$ where $d_i=(s_i^2-\lambda)^{-1}$ if $s_i^2-\lambda\ne0$ or $d_i=0$ otherwise.