# Number of real roots of polynomial equation $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{a_j}{(\lambda_j+x )^2}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, roots

In one of my recent answers to an optimization question (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4877663/1231520)), I came across the following equation:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n  \frac{a_j}{(\lambda_j+x  )^2}=1$$

where $a_j>0, \lambda_j \ge 0, j=1,...,n$. After doing some numerical checks, I realized that this equation always has **two real roots** (try it yourself [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B2%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B4%2Cx%2B.5%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B2%2Cx%2B.5%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B7%2Cx%2B.6%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2Cx%2B7%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%3D1)).

One may note that the equation can be written based on a polynomial with $2n$ degrees.

Is there any formal proof or counterexample for this observation?

Comment: I need to add that the smallest root of the equation is always negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assume that $\lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \ldots \le \lambda_n$. The function
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n  \frac{a_j}{(\lambda_j+x  )^2}
$$
is continuous on the open interval $(-\lambda_1, \infty)$ with
$$
 \lim_{x \to (-\lambda_1)+} f(x) = +\infty \, , \, \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0 \, .
$$
It follows that $f(x) = 1$ has a solution in $(-\lambda_1, \infty)$. (Actually exactly one solution in that interval because $f$ is strictly decreasing there.)

In the same way one can show that $f(x) = 1$ has (exactly) one solution in the interval $(-\infty, -\lambda_n)$.

This shows that $f(x) =1$ has *at least* two real solutions. There can be additional solutions (one or two in each of the intervals $(-\lambda_{k+1}, -\lambda_k)$). For example, the equation
$$
 \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac {1}{(x+5)^2} + \frac{1}{(x+10)^2}  = 1
$$
has six real solutions ([WolfamAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+1%2F%28x%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28x%2B5%29%5E2+%2B+1%2F%28x%2B10%29%5E2+%3D1)).

Comment: Thanks for you answer! How can we guarantee that the function $f(x)$ cannot become $1$ in the inner interval $(\lambda_1, \lambda _n)$?

Comment: @Amir: You cannot guarantee that. $f(x) = 1$ may have additional solutions in the intervals ($\lambda_k, \lambda_{k+1})$, depending on the coefficients.

Comment: Could you design a counter-example? I could not find any yet (you may check it in the link provided in the OP).

Comment: @Amir: I have added an example.

Comment: I guess you meant $-\lambda_{n,1}$..

Comment: All of the parameters $\lambda_j, j=1,...,n$ are **non-negative** . They are actually the eigenvalues of a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix.

Comment: @Amir: Please see the updated example.